# Merging knights

Tags: optimization, chess

A standard 8x8 chess grid is filled with knights. Each turn you can issue a move in one of 8 directions available to a chess knight. This will move **all** the knights in that direction. If a knight would jump out of board then it stays in its location. Otherwise the knight will jump in the issued direction. If a knight lands on another knight then they merge into one. For example, issuing the move "2 up and 1 right" from the starting grid would give you the following grid:

[image: chessboard willed with knights, except with A6 to A1 empty, as well as B1 to G1 and B2 to G2 empty]

Is it possible to merge all the knights into one? What is the least number of turns required for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be optimal.

> 13 moves:
>  [image: Merging knights]

Confirmed optimal via exhaustive search. [Pastebin link to code](https://pastebin.com/W2RGAQhz)

Search depth 12 returns in about 40 seconds with no solutions. Search depth 13 returns in about 5 minutes, finding 68 solutions with first move forced ESE to avoid primary symmetries. The first of these is shown here in generated output:

> ```
> Step 1:
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  N N N N N N N N
>
> Step 2:
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>  N N N N N N N N
>
> Step 3:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . N N .
>  . . . . . N N .
>  . . . N N N N .
>  . . . N N N N .
>  . . . N N N N N
>  N N N N N N N N
>
> Step 4:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . N N N N N
>  N N N N N N N N
>
> Step 5:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . . . N N N
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . . . . . N N
>
> Step 6:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . N N N N N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>
> Step 7:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . N N
>  . . . . N N N N
>
> Step 8:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . N N N N
>
> Step 9:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . N N N
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . N
>
> Step 10:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . N
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . N N
>
> Step 11:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . N
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . N
>
> Step 12:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . N . .
>  . . . . . . . N
>
> Step 13:
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . N
> ```

Comment: Nice job. Is this using a computer program?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Not yet.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Exhaustive search confirms this to be optimal.

Comment: I confirmed optimality via integer linear programming.  The minimum number of knights after each move is $46, 32, 18, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1$, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

I was originally preparing what I thought was a better solution than I actually have, when another answer was posted. But I'll post it anyway, because I had already reached the answer, and because the sequence is different.

I also have it in

> **13 moves**
>
>  **Move 1**: 2 up and 1 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 2**: 2 up and 1 left
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & \quad \\ \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 3**: 2 up and 1 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 4**: 1 up and 2 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 5**: 1 down and 2 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & N & N & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 6**: 1 up and 2 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 7**: 1 down and 2 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 8**: 2 down and 1 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 9**: 1 up and 2 left
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 10**: 1 up and 2 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 11**: 1 up and 2 left
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 12**: 2 down and 1 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$
>
>  **Move 13**: 2 up and 1 right
>  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & N \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad & \quad \\ \hline \end{array}$

It was generated by a recursive C program in under a second. I reduced the search space:

> For any given board, there are eight possible outcomes.
>  I explored only those outcomes with the least, or equal least, survivors.
>  For example if the eight moves left 4, 6, 6, 8, 4, 8, 5, 9 survivors,
>  I explored only the two with 4 survivors.
>
>  Later, I also explored those outcomes equal to or 1 greater than the least.
>  So for the above example I explored the ones with 4, 4, and 5 survivors.
>  It took a while longer, but no better solutions were found.

Comment: One minor remark: In chess notation, the abbreviation "K" is used for kings, not knights. Knights are abbreviated either "N" or (more old-fastioned and mostly obsolete) "Kt".

Comment: @trolley813 updated, thanks.

Comment: Exhaustive search confirms these to be optimal. See edit for link to code.