# Merging knights and blocking rooks

Tags: optimization, chess

A chess grid is filled with knights and rooks as shown in the following diagram.

Each turn you can issue a move in one of 8 directions available to a chess knight. This will move **all** the knights in that direction. If a knight would jump out of board or onto a rook then it stays in its current location. Otherwise the knight will jump in the issued direction. If a knight lands on another knight then they merge into one. Starting from the following position, is it possible to merge all the knights into one? What is the least number of turns required to do so? You may need to use a computer to solve this puzzle.

[image: starting position of the chessboard filled with knights and rooks. The Knights occupy the four centre squares, and are also arranged in four lots of hollow three by three squares with each square flush with a board corner. Every other position is filled by a Rook.]

Comment: So, to clarify, rooks never move, right?

Comment: correct rooks never move

Comment: I read the title as "merging knights and blocking rocks," and proceeded to be surprised by the distinct lack of rocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution

> **One** knight remains after **16 moves**
>
>  [image]

I don't know if this is optimal, the search was not exhaustive.

*Found 2 solutions with a hand-made C program.*

Comment: I can't see anything in the rules that stops you merging the last two knights from your final position. E.g. (probably far from optimal, just the first way I spotted "by eye") 1D2L, 2U1L, 2U1R, 1D2L, 2U1L, 1U2R

Comment: @fljx well spotted but the last one should be 1D2L from c7 to a6. Six more moves is a lot deeper than my non-exhaustive search. I'm fiddling with its efficency and trying to shrink the search space. The [previous version](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114750/merging-knights) wasn't so demanding.

Comment: 1U2R (a6-c7) works (rook on e8 blocks the c7 knight)

Comment: WSW, SSW, NNW, ENE

Comment: @fljx thanks for the prompting - now found a solution.

Comment: Ah, I see you found an equivalent end.

Comment: @DanielMathias, yes, same number of moves, but not copied from the suggestions.

Comment: Very nice! I wonder if we can improve it?

Comment: Yes, but by how much?

Comment: Starting from your position after move three, an exhaustive search finds no better solutions.

Comment: @DanielMathias as with the previous puzzle, I exhaustively explored all boards with the lowest number of survivors. So of the 8 moves for any given layout, only those with lowest or equal lowest knights. Again as that puzzle, I also exhautively searched all boards with the (least + 1) knights. Of course, the first board only has 1 possible move, because it is symmetrical. I'll see if it can be fully exhaustive.

Comment: I have an estimate of about 4 hours for a fully exhaustive search. Currently running search from position after 2 moves.

Comment: I confirmed optimality via integer linear programming. The minimum number of knights after each move is 26, 19, 14, 11, 9, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, respectively.

Comment: @RobPratt I'm curious, how do you apply integer linear programming here?

Comment: @Magma I added an answer just now.

Answer (score 4):

By request, here's the integer linear programming formulation I used.  Let $C$ be the set of $36$ cells that are not blocked by rooks.  Let $t$ be the target number of steps, and let $S=\{0,\dots,t\}$ be the set of steps.  Let $D=\{(d_i,d_j)\in \mathbb{Z}^2:|d_i d_j| = 2\}$ be the set of eight directions.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j,s}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is occupied by a knight at step $s$.  Let binary decision variable $y_{d_i,d_j,s}$ indicate whether direction $(d_i,d_j)$ is chosen at step $s$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{(i,j)\in C} x_{i,j,t}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(d_i,d_j) \in D} y_{d_i,d_j,s} &= 1 &&\text{for $s \in S \setminus \{0\}$} \tag1\\
x_{i,j,0} &= 1 && \text{for $(i,j) \in C$} \tag2\\
\sum_{\substack{(d_i,d_j) \in D:\\ (i+d_i,j+d_j) \notin C}} y_{d_i,d_j,s} +
x_{i,j,s-1} - 1 &\le x_{i,j,s} && \text{for $(i,j) \in C, s \in S \setminus \{0\}$} \tag3\\
y_{d_i,d_j,s} + x_{i-d_i,j-d_j,s-1} - 1 &\le x_{i,j,s} && \text{for $(i,j) \in C, s \in S \setminus \{0\}, (d_i,d_j) \in D: (i-d_i,j-d_j) \in C$} \tag4\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects exactly one direction at each step.
Constraint $(2)$ fixes the initial configuration of knights at step $0$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces the rule that a knight that cannot move in the chosen direction stays in place.  That is, $$(y_{d_i,d_j,s} \land x_{i,j,s-1}) \implies x_{i,j,s}.$$
Constraint $(4)$ enforces the rule that a knight that can move in the chosen direction does so.  That is,
$$(y_{d_i,d_j,s} \land x_{i-d_i,j-d_j,s-1}) \implies x_{i,j,s}.$$

I solved the problem for each $t$ from $1$ to $16$ to obtain the optimal values
$$26, 19, 14, 11, 9, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1.$$

> So $t=16$ is the minimum number of steps needed to yield one knight.

Comment: My present solution goes in two stages. First it exhaustively finds S survivors after M moves, removes duplicate solutions (but not symmetries), and then exhaustively continues to find 1 survivor after N moves. Strangely, when I set S=2 and M=13 from your result it doesn't find a solution for N, but for N+1. Similarly when I set S=3 and M=10. But when I set S=4 and M=11, it does. So aiming for the minimum survivors possible at each move, does not solve it in the minimum moves.

Comment: Yes, the behavior you describe is a known pitfall of greedy algorithms. I did not mention it in my answer, but after solving step $s$, I also added a constraint that the number of knights after $s$ steps must be at least (but not necessarily equal to) the minimum just determined. This optional constraint helps prune the search space without losing optimality.